# string B is within string A - Python beginner programming

Tags: python-3.x

Help me solve this without using .split()
Return True if and only if string A contains string B. so For example, if the first parameter is **'I like icecream'**, and the second parameter is **'icecream'**, then the function should return **True.**

**However** if the first parameter is **'I like icecream'**, and the second parameter is **'ice'**, then the function should return **False**, since the word 'ice' is not the same word as 'icecream'

Comment: This isn't a question.

Comment: good point, my bad for forgetting to do so

Answer (score 1):

Just try this:

```
def isWithin(word1, word2):
    return word2 in word1.split()
```

---

```
>>> isWithin('I like icecream', 'icecream')
True
>>> isWithin('I like icecream', 'ice')
False
>>>
```

Comment: Is there another way of doing so without using the .split()?